# Change image source and opacity jquery problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a div that contains text next to a b&w image. The entire div is set to 50% opacity. Upon hover over this div, I want to change the opacity to 100%, while also changing the source of the image (from the b&w one to the color). The functionality is fine; however, when it's hovered over, the opacity changes slightly **before** the image source changes, and it definitely looks a little funky.  I've tried preloading the images, but that doesn't seem to change anything - still a slight delay in changing the img source.

Here is what my code looks like (the images have the almost same source, just the suffix is different, thus the strange looking code):

```
$('.character').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var full_src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var half_src = full_src.split("-");
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', half_src[0] + '-color.png');
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);
});

$('.character').on('mouseleave', function() {
    var full_src = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var half_src = full_src.split("-");
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', half_src[0] + '-bw.png');
    $(this).css('opacity', .5);
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Threw together a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3WZ7J/ - does seem to work correctly most of the time, my images might be too large or not preloading correctly.

Comment: Seems ok to me: http://jsfiddle.net/jdfDG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait for the image to load before changing the opacity of the `div`

```
$('.character').on('mouseenter', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var full_src = $this.find('img').attr('src');
    var half_src = full_src.split("-");
    $this.find('img').load(function(){
        $this.css('opacity', 1);
    }).attr('src', half_src[0] + '-color.png');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3WZ7J/6/)

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is .promise() to force the order in which the operations take place, so that the opacity won't change until the image has swapped out. Some info here: http://api.jquery.com/promise/